# hoew do i combine files split and created by winrar back into original file (compressed zip package, i think)?

Tags: winrar

I have several folders of files created by WinRAR, I believe.  They are files that exist in groups of 3, with extensions .0, .1, and .IDX.

I have old data that I believe are old pictures or movies.  I'm pretty sure I separated them with WinRAR playing around with it and just recently came upon the old files and was hoping to be able to check the files out, they might have some good memories in them if I can recompile them.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just open the primary archive? Files split by WinRAR into the type of archives you seem to be describing should automatically be put back together during the decompression process.

Comment: ok... when you say decompression process, are you referring to extracting them?  which im assuming has to be done through WinRAR, which im unfamiliar with... but doesn't the process of "decompression" that we're talking about entail combining the files together while simultaneously extracting the original data?

Comment: Yes, I am referring to extracting them through WinRAR. And yes, during decompression/extraction the files are typically "combined" together automatically by WinRAR while simultaneously extracting the original data. Note that it may be possible to use [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org) as well (as an alternative to WinRAR) or perhaps even some other archival utilities, assuming they support `.rar` format files. In any case, if you don't know what file is the primary archive, you can likely select them all and extract them together at once.

Answer (score 0):

First, this is a very basic feature of most compression utilities. It's not as useful today, but back before large USB drives became common, being able to split archives was a necessary feature.

Because this is a basic feature, it's very well documented in the help files and in tutorials online. It's also very simple.

Typically, you simple make sure all of the parts of the multi-part archive are in the same directory, select the first one, and begin the extraction process either by double-clicking on it to open it with the utility, or by right-clicking and specifying the utility to open the archive with or the command to run against it.

If you are trying to take what are currently multiple parts of a multi-part archive and create a single larger archive because you no longer need to be concerned about the maximum file size, you must first decompress the archives, turning them into their original, decompressed form, and then you simply re-compress them into a single archive file, using  whichever settings are appropriate to do this.